# MethodHandle Lookup Issues

Tags: java, events, lambda, reflection

I've recently needed to make a relatively simple events system. (Id -> Consumer) This would be able to subscribe a `Method` based off annotation. Then I remembered that Java isn't C# and attempted to look for a way to accomplish this. After many similar threads, I came across this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/alexengrig/df1797d4d07c9f5d521d8c33c2a56563), and attempted to implement it. I did so successfully, however did not realize early enough that the `MethodHandles.lookup()` method is location specific and only applies to the class that calls it.

*ConsumerFactory*

```
public class ConsumerFactory {
    private final Method consumerMethod;
    private final MethodType consumerMethodType;

    private final Map<Method, Consumer<?>> methodCache = new HashMap<>();

    public ConsumerFactory() {
        consumerMethod = findLambdaMethod(Consumer.class);
        consumerMethodType = MethodType.methodType(consumerMethod.getReturnType(), consumerMethod.getParameterTypes());
    }

    public <T, L> Consumer<T> createConsumer(L instance, Method implMethod) throws Throwable {
        Consumer<T> cached = (Consumer<T>) methodCache.get(implMethod);
        if(cached==null) {
            Class<?> implType = implMethod.getDeclaringClass();

            MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup().in(implType);
            MethodType implMethodType = MethodType.methodType(implMethod.getReturnType(), implMethod.getParameterTypes());
            MethodHandle implMethodHandle = lookup.findVirtual(implType, implMethod.getName(), implMethodType);

            MethodType invokedMethodType = MethodType.methodType(Consumer.class, implType);

            CallSite metaFactory = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(
                    lookup,
                    consumerMethod.getName(), invokedMethodType, consumerMethodType,
                    implMethodHandle, implMethodType);

            MethodHandle factory = metaFactory.getTarget();
            Consumer<T> consumer = (Consumer<T>) factory.invoke(instance);
            methodCache.put(implMethod, consumer);
            return consumer;
        }
        return cached;
    }

    private Method findLambdaMethod(Class<?> type) {
        if (!type.isInterface()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This must be interface: " + type);
        }
        Method[] methods = getAllMethods(type);
        if (methods.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No methods in: " + type.getName());
        }
        Method targetMethod = null;
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (isInterfaceMethod(method)) {
                if (targetMethod != null) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("This isn't functional interface: " + type.getName());
                }
                targetMethod = method;
            }
        }
        if (targetMethod == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No method in: " + type.getName());
        }
        return targetMethod;
    }
    private Method[] getAllMethods(Class<?> type) {
        LinkedList<Method> result = new LinkedList<>();
        Class<?> current = type;
        do {
            result.addAll(Arrays.asList(current.getMethods()));
        } while ((current = current.getSuperclass()) != null);
        return result.toArray(new Method[0]);
    }
    private boolean isInterfaceMethod(Method method) {
        return !method.isDefault() && Modifier.isAbstract(method.getModifiers());
    }
}
```

Is their anything I could do to still have this sort of idea function? Ideally end up as something like `Map<String, Consumer<Event>>`. I was considering forcefully creating a `Lookup` class, but I'm not sure if that would be the best idea.

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is that you get an exception like `LambdaConversionException: Invalid caller: …`, the problem is in this line:

```java
MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup().in(implType);
```

You just have to change it to

```java
MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
```

This performs the operation in the context of the `ConsumerFactory` and requires that `ConsumerFactory` is allowed to access the target method. But if your current code succeeded in performing `findVirtual` on the lookup object and proceeded to end up at the exception above, it implies that the accessibility is given.

But note that the code is unnecessarily complicated. The `getAllMethods` iterates over the superclass hierarchy despite the `getMethods()` call on a `Class` does already return all `public` methods, including the methods inherited from super interfaces while `getSuperclass()` will return `null` for an interface anyway.

Further, as explained in [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/322715/2711488) there’s rarely a need for a `LinkedList` and this use case is no exception.

Then, `isAbstract` precludes `isDefault`, so this test is redundant. On the other hand, methods matching a `public` method of `java.lang.Object` must be skipped. Failing to do so makes it fail for, e.g. `Comparator`. The question is whether you want to fix `findLambdaMethod` to cover all cases or drop it completely as you’re only interested in `Consumer` for which we know that the method is `void accept(Object)`.

Also, the conversion of a `Method` to a `MethodHandle` doesn’t need to be done by hand. Considering all simplifications, we end up with

```java
public class ConsumerFactory {
    private final Map<Method, Consumer<?>> methodCache = new HashMap<>();

    public ConsumerFactory() {}

    public <T, L> Consumer<T> createConsumer(L instance, Method implMethod) throws Throwable {
        Consumer<T> cached = (Consumer<T>) methodCache.get(implMethod);
        if(cached==null) {
            // avoid cryptic errors by checking this explicitly
            if(implMethod.getParameterCount() != 1 || Modifier.isStatic(implMethod.getModifiers()))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("not suitable for Consumer: " + implMethod);

            MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
            MethodHandle implMethodHandle = lookup.unreflect(implMethod);
            MethodType implMethodType = MethodType.methodType(void.class, implMethodHandle.type().parameterType(1));
            MethodType invokedMethodType = MethodType.methodType(Consumer.class, implMethod.getDeclaringClass());

            CallSite metaFactory = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(
                    lookup, "accept", invokedMethodType,
                    MethodType.methodType(void.class, Object.class),
                    implMethodHandle, implMethodType);

            Consumer<T> consumer = (Consumer<T>) metaFactory.getTarget().invoke(instance);
            methodCache.put(implMethod, consumer);
            return consumer;
        }
        return cached;
    }
}
```

But keep in mind that you can also create a `Consumer` calling `invoke` on a `Method`, even via lambda expression. So the code above is not strictly needed. Calling `invoke` on a `Method` may also serve as a fallback if the `LambdaMetafactory` approach fails.

If you want to keep the method for finding the method to implement for a functional interface, here’s a revised version:

```java
private Method findLambdaMethod(Class<?> type) {
    if(!type.isInterface()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This must be interface: " + type);
    }
    Method targetMethod = null;
    for(Method method: type.getMethods()) {
        if(isCandidate(method)) {
            if(targetMethod != null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("This isn't functional interface: " + type.getName());
            }
            targetMethod = method;
        }
    }
    if(targetMethod == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This isn't functional interface: " + type.getName());
    }
    return targetMethod;
}
private boolean isCandidate(Method method) {
    if(!Modifier.isAbstract(method.getModifiers()))
        return false;

    // check for redeclarations of public java.lang.Object methods
    if(method.getParameterCount() == 0) {
        String name = method.getName();
        return !name.equals("hashCode") && !name.equals("toString");
    }
    if(method.getParameterCount() == 1)
        return !method.getName().equals("equals") || method.getParameterTypes()[0] != Object.class;

    return true;
}
```